# Работа с пользовательскими данными

Tags: html, get

Скажите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь. Вопрос такой: надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст из формы переходил на другую страницу и там становился названием страницы.

Comment: поиск по форуму сделать нужно и найдешь один в один вопрос и ответ на него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="gambit.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label>Ваше название страницы:<br></label> 
    <input name="go" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
```

далее скрипт для gambit.php

```
$rel= $_POST['go'];
< title> $rel </title>
```